# Sort scraped Data into table on server page

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Hi Im working on a scraper script so far Ive been able scrape from 2 elements . At this testing state I do not have a database setup thus far. So I thought Id just Sort this straight to my server page. This is my working code

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', function (error, response,
    html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var HomeTeam = "";
        var AwayTeam = "";

        $('div.score_home_txt.score_cell.wrap').each(function (i, element) {
            var a = $(this).text();
            var a = a.toLowerCase();
            HomeTeam += "<tr><td>" + a + "</td>";
            //console.log(a);

        });
        $('div.score_away_txt.score_cell.wrap').each(function (i, element) {
            var b = $(this).text();
            var b = b.toLowerCase();
            AwayTeam += "<td>" + b + "</td><tr>";
            //console.log(b);

        });

        var html = "<table><th>" + "HomeTeam</th><th>AwayTeam</th>" + HomeTeam + AwayTeam + "</table>"
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        res.end(html);
    }
});
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server is running at http://178.62.253.206:8080/');
```

The plan was to sort this in a table with 2 Columns Home in Col A and Away in ColB, But im a little unsure how to write this so it gets sorted correctly.

The code above sort this into a single row. Ive tried a few different approaches but haven figured out the correct way yet :/

Any help would be much appreciated

Frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a common parent, looking at the website you are scraping `.score_line` looks like a reasonable option

```
// assume we're always going to return html
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
// hit API
request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', (err, response, html) => {
  if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) {
    // log error internally
    console.error(err ? err.message : `API status code: ${response.statusCode}`);
    // return client response
    return res.status(500).send('<b>Internal Server Error</b>');
  }

  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const rows = [];
  // find each row
  $('.score_line').each((i, el) => {
    // extract each column
    const homeScore = el.find('.score_home.score_cell.wrap').text().toLowerCase();
    const awayScore = el.find('.score_away.score_cell.wrap').text().toLowerCase();
    // build row
    rows.push(`<tr><td>${homeScore}</td><td>${awayScore}</td></tr>`);
  });
  // build & send table
  res.send(`<table>${rows.join('')}</table>`);
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I most admit I can not find .score line. I see that You made a lot of changes to the code. I'm not that tech savvy and I couldn't get this to work (just copied and pasted everything into index.js)

Comment: @Frederik84 I've modernised the code a bit to use the latest Node syntax, what's the error?

Comment: I copied the code as you have written it and stored it as index.js , when I try to run  it I get a bunch of errors in the console. Referenceerror res is not defined

Comment: But im starting to think that I should just set up mongoDB maybe its better t handle the data that way..

Comment: @Frederik84 you still need the outer server code (that would explain the `res is not defined` error). I omitted that for brevity.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this I was able to get it working now . I suspect your code is the better one but the one posted above was working out of the box . With my skill set I dont understand either of the codes . I guess I have alot more to learn :)  But really I appreciate all the inputs

Comment: @Frederik84 this should work out the box too, you would just replace this code with the body of your `createServer` callback. FWIW this code is more efficient than the accepted answer as that is doing 3 iterations where as this is only doing one... (well two if you count the `join` but I presumed this would be more efficient than all the string concatenations!).

Comment: Hi I guess in all fairness I should award your answer the checkmark , as I said I suspected your code to be more efficient , but that is quite hard to judge for a new developer like myself .  I was able to get kgangadhar code to work right away and I didn't quite understand how to implement your suggestion into my index,js file Also the overall goal is to extract around 10 col from that site. I have gotten 3 for today and im quite happy with my progression so far ..